# What is the right location for public app files on IOS (CORDOVA)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm downloading and saving remote files with my hybrid app, everything works fine so far, i used the cordova.file.dataDirectory to avoid icloud sync.

The thing is, the downloaded files never got indexed by the native file pickers of the device. I tested it with every available filesystem for ios and got nothing.

Simplified function to download and save:

```
var fileSystem = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

$http("server_url").then(function (success) {
  $cordovaFile.writeFile(fileSystem, "future_path_name", success.data, true).then(
    function (success) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
    })
});
```

Comment: you can use document directory or library directory see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#ios-persistent-storage-location

Comment: iOS file pickers only show document providers, so to make your app files available you should make your app to be a document provider. Some links about document providers https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/document-providers/, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html

Comment: Thanks, I managed to attach the document provider extension to the project and works. The problem is that i need to write files to the app group’s shared container instead of the application container.

Comment: @doriak How were you able to write the files to the app group's shared container instead of the app's container in Cordova?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you share with us?